# Online C++ compiler with input stream?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, codepad

I kinda like [codepad online editor (supports C++)](http://codepad.org/), but I'd like to use some [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)s which is not possible with codepad.

Is there some online C++ compiler that supports input streams? Is that even possible?

Comment: A quick test of codepad shows it appears to support input and output (string) streams just fine (see: http://codepad.org/YstAFSu5 )

Comment: @Chad: Somehow you missed the part where it said 'but I'd like to use some [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)s'

Comment: I have 'hackish' half-joke solution to this. It turns out there is an input file that you can somewhat rely on to be there and that you can fully control...

Comment: @sehe: nice, kind of an inverse quine.

Comment: http://cpp.sh/ supports `scanf()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[IDEOne](http://ideone.com/) supports passing in the input; you can specify it in a `<textarea>`.

Comment: @Xeo: You can specify alternative input after compilation and run it again (post-compilation). Perhaps you just wanted to say it isn't _terminal emulation_ (interactive) (but that wasn't quite the question)

Comment: @sehe: Well, yeah, that's what I meant. I tend to forget about that little input window at the bottom after running the code.

Answer (score 9):

[ *Disclaimer: I prefer ideone.com (has c++0x support as well)* ]

Getting very pedantic, you could stuff your input inside the source file by playing this dirty trick:

http://codepad.org/fjtHRgof

```
/* just skip the first two (!!!) lines when reading from t.cpp
602.030024387
423.927317911
520.43881927
131.655014874
35.7455352247
548.735653436
714.556123804
876.948673754
379.105540406
885.096900058
192.734103705
116.365922766
363.998415895
216.268387112
958.684513705

*/ // end of fake input

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("t.cpp");
    std::cout << ifs.rdbuf() << std::flush;
}
```

Comment: How can we extend this for other programming languages? I was wondering if something like this would work for c.

Comment: @nikhil, just use C specific file IO? `fopen()` etc?

Answer (score 2):

[`Rextester`](http://rextester.com/) has an input box as well and has a more usable interface than [`ideone`](http://ideone.com/) which I have always felt was very clunky.

[`Coliru`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) allows you to use [multiple files](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18md3rLdgD9f5Wro3i7YYopJBFb_6MPCO8-0ihtxHoyM/edit?pli=1), so you can create an file with your data and do something like this to input into your program:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -W -Wall main.cpp && cat /Archive/{{id}}/main.cpp | a.out
```

Note, [`LWS`](http://liveworkspace.org/) also has a nice interface and an input box but has been in `read-only` mode for a while now and it is not clear it is coming back online anytime soon if at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://optimizedbits.com . There you can also compile your code by providing your own stream of multiple inputs.

For just one input stream, simply write the input. For multiple input test cases, follow:

```
input1
<TESTCASE>
input2
<TESTCASE>
....
```

Regarding the possibility of input stream: See no body builds a compiler on their own. Everybody utilizes some  standards like gcc in the back-end. All online compiler websites work around a architecture which involves the following flow(example:C++):

```
1) read_code_user
2) Save it as variablename.cpp
3) Use a queuing framework. Then execute g++ variablename.cpp. Further, various libraries are utilized which can pipe stdin, stdout and stderr.
```

Answer (score 1):

try http://compileonline.com/
enter your input in STDIN